# Integration of logistic function by partial fractions

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

An elementary calculus text defines the "logistic function" as the following:

$$\int \frac{1}{P(1 - mP)} \, dP$$

The solution given is $$\ln|\frac{P}{(1 - mP)}| $$

My incorrect solution is the following:

$$ \frac{1}{P(1 - mP)} = \frac{A}{P} + \frac{B}{1 -mP} $$

=> $$1 = A - Amp + BP $$
=> $$ A = 1 $$ and $$ -(1)mP = BP = 0$$ => $$p(-m + B) = 0$$ => $$B = m$$

Therefore,

$$\int \frac{1}{P(1 - mP)} \, dP = \int \frac{1}{P} dP + \int \frac{m}{1 - mp} dP = ln|P| + m(ln|1 -mP|) + C$$

...which is not quite right.

It's possible my eyes are glazing over something obvious. Either way, please let me know which step is fallacious.

Thanks.

Comment: When you integrate $\frac{1}{1-mp}$ you obtain a factor of $\frac{1}{-m}$ (coming from integration by substitution, chain rule, whatever you want to call it).

Comment: Derp! That was it. The $$m$$ for some reason threw me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simple - your integration $\int \frac{m}{1 - mP}dP$.  You need $u$ substitution.  If $u = 1 - mP$, then $du = -m\,dP$.  However, the numerator is just $m\,dP$ so we need to move the negative over: $-du = m\,dP$.  Then this becomes:

$$-\int\frac{du}{u} = -\ln|u| = -\ln|1 - mP|$$

Incorporating this into your final answer gives:

$$\ln|P| - \ln|1 - mP| + C$$

Logarithm rules then apply to transform to the final result (you can take subtracted logarithms and convert them to divisors inside the logarithm function):

$$\ln\,\biggr|\frac{P}{1 - mP}\biggr| + C$$

Comment: Thanks, yeah. As mentioned in my reply to the first comment, for some reason my brain was not registering that and trying to just integrate the entire denominator as if it were a single thing.